# What is the work around for Hibernate 4 persistence support for org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hi All I am new to Spring and am building application using the following dependencies

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
                <spring.framework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
```

I am not able to persist the objects with fields with datatype DateTime from the class  org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.

```
@Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
    @Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }
```

Can anybody suggest how to use the joda DateTime.

Comment: If you are getting some error stack trace, it would help if you post it here.

Comment: I got the resolution. org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime is probably not supported by the hibernate 4.
When the type is changed to @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime") it worked fine. I had to add the following library as well.
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
   <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0.CR3</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: This is the updated method for persisting in database.
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
 @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
 public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
  return createdDate;
 }

Answer (score 1):

I had been trying this for entire day finally got the solution as the following. org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime class persistence is not supported by higher versions of hibernate. Rather we use some very specific libraries like the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> org.jadira.usertype </groupId>
    <artifactId> usertype.core </artifactId>
    <version> 3.0.0.CR3 </version>
</dependency>
```

This is how we can persist the data in the database for audit purpose.

```
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
```